# How to calculate day counts of previous month?

Tags: java, calendar

I would like to retrieve day counts of previous month. I can get day counts of current month by

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), 1);
    int currentMonthDaysCount = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    System.out.println(currentMonthDaysCount);
```

So , I tried to get day counts of previous month as

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH - 1), 1);
    int previousMonthDaysCount = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    System.out.println(previousMonthDaysCount);
```

I got `30` at my console. What I am wrong ? This month is **August** and previous month **July** should produce `31`.

Comment: I've always used a dirty trick: I set the calendar to the first day of the current month, and then I subtract a day (calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1)). And then I simply check what day of the month it is.

Comment: @Gimby Yes thank you , your comment is what I actually want to do. Thanks thanks thanks. At real , I would like to calculate days from previous month.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are subtracting from a `Calendar` constant instead of subtracting from the value you get from that constant.

Change:

```
calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH - 1), 1);
```

With:

```
calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1, 1);
```

Easier solution:

```
calendar.roll(Calendar.MONTH, false);
```

... will "roll" one month "down".

Comment: That is one problem. I wonder what happens when the current month is January.

Comment: wow, I didn't even realize that the roll method existed. That's way cleaner than my hack fix :)

Comment: @Gimby sure comes in handy yes ;)